# Google Analytics 4 - user data import not appearing in analysis hub

Tags: user-data, google-analytics-4

I am trying to import user level data into GA 4 property.

I have uploaded csv file with 5 columns - all already existing as custom dimensions in GA4.

I have joined these 5 columns with the existing custom dimensions in data mapping, but the data isn`t showing up in analysis hub.

Has anyone faced similar issue when importing user data in GA4?